# Несовпадение хэшей в PHP и MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Может немного глупый вопрос, но всё же не мог не задать..

В MySQL задал пароль 123ijdb - хэш 727eee025601b4279260d8aa0a7aa0cc

Проверяю:

```
<?php
$pass = '123';
$password = md5(pass . 'ijdb'); //123ijdb
echo $password;
?>
```

На выходе имеем всё тот же хэш 727eee025601b4279260d8aa0a7aa0cc

А теперь передам данные из текстового поля формы:

```
$password = md5($pass . 'ijdb');
```

Ввожу 123, а хэш другой - ac477232f1188855df4214b94cafab2b

А если сделать вот так:

```
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$password = md5($pass . 'ijdb');
```

На выходе "правильный" хэш 727eee025601b4279260d8aa0a7aa0cc

Собственно интересно почему так, если сохранили хэш в переменную то всё работает, а если нет, то не работает, но ведь пароль не изменяется.

Comment: В md5(pass . 'ijdb'); - pass это не переменная. Поменяйте на $pass

Comment: То есть php сам должен догадаться, что Вы хотите, чтобы в $pass были какие-то данные?

Answer (score 1):

А откуда тут данные в переменной $pass появятся?

```
$password = md5($pass . 'ijdb');
```

Вот тут правильное присвоение, почитайте про $_POST/$_GET переменные.

```
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$password = md5($pass . 'ijdb');
```